# Can't commit svn controlled directory when referencing through symlink

Tags: svn, version-control, symlink

I have a problem that I describe poorly in another question. I'm posting this to make it more clear what I want to do, and what problem I'm encountering. There is a highly-voted answer, but it doesn't actually address my problem (short story: I'm not trying to add a symlinked directory to my version-controlled project).

**If you already know how subversion works, skip to below to get the actual question.**

I am at the command line, and the current working directory is my home directory.

```
$> pwd
/home/user
```

I have an svn project. Let's say it's called `some_project`. I want to check the project out to `real_directory/`.

```
$> svn checkout http://svnhost.net/some_project real_directory
A    real_directory/index.php
...
A    real_directory/robots.txt
Checked out revision 1143.
```

I haven't `cd`ed into that directory; I'm still outside of it, in my home directory:
    $> pwd
    /home/user

Yet I can still use svn commands on files `real_directory/`, even though it's not my current working directory

```
$> svn status real_directory/
$> touch real_directory/new_file.txt
$> svn status real_directory/
?      real_directory/new_file.txt
$> svn add real_directory/new_file.txt
A         real_directory/new_file.txt
```

I'm pointing this out to clarify misconceptions presented in the other question. Note that I added a file to the project, while still outside of the version-controlled directory. I can do this because of the existence of the `.svn/` directory in the `real_directory` directory. This is what makes `real_directory/` contain the `some_project` subversion project, even though it has a different name.

```
$> ls real_directory/.svn
all-wcprops  entries  format  prop-base  props  text-base  tmp
```

( If you already know this, please bear with me -- my original question had a well-voted answer that gave wrong information about the ability to do this with subversion! )

This is the syntax of the `svn` command:

```
svn [svn-controlled directory] command
```

If you don't specify the directory, svn will assume you're talking about the current directory. So all of these are equivalent (current working directory is in the shell prompt):

```
[ /home/user ]$ svn status real_directory/
A      real_directory/new_file.txt
[ /home/user ]$ cd real_directory/
[ /home/user/real_directory ]$ svn status .
A      new_file.txt
[ /home/user/real_directory ]$ svn status
A      new_file.txt
```

So, to recap: I can do anything I want *while not inside* the version controlled directory, *just as if I were inside of it*, simply by specifying the directory when I issue my svn commands.

OK, now that *that's* out of the way, **here's the problem**:

When I create a symlink to the subversion controlled directory, svn recognizes it for commands such as `add` and `status`, but not for `commit`!

Here is the symlink directory working just like the real directory when I add files and ask its status:

```
$> svn status real_directory/
A      real_directory/new_file.txt
$> ln -s real_directory/ symlink
$> svn status symlink
A      symlink/new_file.txt
$> svn status real_directory/
A      real_directory/new_file.txt
$> touch symlink/another_new_file.txt
$> svn status symlink
?      symlink/another_new_file.txt
A      symlink/new_file.txt
$> svn add symlink/another_new_file.txt
A         symlink/another_new_file.txt
$> svn status symlink/
A      symlink/another_new_file.txt
A      symlink/new_file.txt
```

See how `symlink/` acts just like `real_directory/` for the purposes of `add` and `status`? **Problem:** this fails on the commit command:

```
$> svn commit symlink/ -m "test commit"
svn: '/home/user' is not a working copy
svn: Can't open file '/home/user/.svn/entries': No such file or directory
```

Huh? That's weird. Svn certainly thinks that file exists when I do `status` and `add`! Maybe it got deleted?

```
$> ls symlink/.svn/entries
symlink/.svn/entries
```

Nope, still there. Does it still have data in it?

```
$> ls -lha !$
ls -lha symlink/.svn/entries
-r--r--r-- 1 user group 14K 2009-12-18 06:36 symlink/.svn/entries
```

Yup, seems to be okay! Alright, forget trying to commit the directory by its symlink. What about just committing the directory by its real name?

```
$> svn commit real_directory/ -m "test commit"
Adding         real_directory/another_new_file.txt
Adding         real_directory/new_file.txt
Transmitting file data ..
Committed revision 1144.
```

Works fine. Why does svn work with `add` and `status` on a symlinked directory, but not `commit`?

Comment: Here is the original, poorly-framed question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924929/svn-cant-commit-from-a-symlinked-directory (and the answer which I think contains factual inaccuracies :)

Comment: I've deleted that answer, since it answers a different question than the one you are actually asking. For what it's worth, I think you'd have better luck asking this on the SVN mailing list: http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=1065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted to the mailing list and got a good answer.

Since the symlink is actually a filesystem file, what's happening is that svn thinks that I'm trying to commit *that symlink as a file* for a project in the current directory -- basically what Ire originally thought I wanted to do!

The proper thing to do is

```
svn commit symbolic_link/*
```